# SharePoint 2013 Content by search webpart Query for selecting only sub sites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search

How to configure the Query in the content by search webpart to show only the subsites in a given site collection? The query should not return any kind of documents or images or any other type of content.

In the query text field I have below:-

```
path:"https://sharepoint.com/teams/MyDevSite"
```

The above query displays everything within that site collection including sub sites, images, documents etc. How to restrict it show only subsites?

Comment: check this one http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/90e0c931-ae97-4f21-b27a-1440cfa25ed7/displaying-subsites-in-content-query-web-part?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clicked the `Keyword Filter` drop down in the query builder, you would've found the option `Only return sites`.  It adds the following to the Query text: `contentclass:STS_Web`.

Comment: This query returns subsites of other subsites. Is it possible to return only subsites of current site collection which is in the path parameter?